# Marketing Cloud Web Analytics Data in Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I've configured Web & Mobile Analytics to track webpage visitors - I can see it properly in the web analytics reports, however, I'm struggling with getting the data to the Predictive Intelligence Data Extensions PI_ and IGO_.

My goal is to capture records to the Data Extensions which present the pages visited by identified users.

I've enabled the Streaming Updates and configured the tracking code to push data to SFMC as follows:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://XXX.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var title = document.title;
    var url = window.location.href;


    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let identified = urlParams.has('subid');
        if (identified === true) {
            let subid = urlParams.get('subid');
            _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "XXX"]);
            _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": subid}]); 
            _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);  
            _etmc.push(["updateItem",
                {
                  "item_type": "content",
                  "item": url,
                  "url": url,
                  "title": title,
                  "available": "Y",
                }
            ]);

        } else {
            _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "XXX"]);
            _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
            _etmc.push(["updateItem",
                {
                  "item_type": "content",
                  "item": url,
                  "url": url,
                  "title": title,
                  "available": "Y"
                }
            ]);
        }

    </script>
```

I also uploaded the Content Catalog with the following format (status:
Successfully processed 5 items):

```
ContentID   Title   Link    Availability
1   Home    https://sfmcdemo.test.com/  Y
2   Shop    https://sfmcdemo.test.com/shop.html Y
3   About   https://sfmcdemo.test.com/about.html    Y
4   Updates https://sfmcdemo.test.com/updates   Y
5   Contact https://sfmcdemo.test.com/contact.html  Y
```

None of these options work for me. I'm not able to see any data being populated in IGO and PI Data Extensions.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue I see:

1) Not passing an `item` in the [track view call](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_track_page_view.htm&type=5)

2) Setting the `item` in your streaming update call to `url` as opposed to the `contentid`

Comment: What is the `item` in the track view call? Is it some sort of a unique identifier of a page?

Comment: the item should be the contentid for the page being viewed that you provide in your catalog

Comment: I updated my `trackPageView` call to `_etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item" : '1' }]);` where `1` is the `contentid` from the uploaded catalog. I also changed that in the streaming update - no result.